# set QPixmap to texture

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I receive a byte array which contains PNG file from network. I need to set this to a pixmap and set it as a texture to my QGlWidget. As I run the program below, pixmap is  in debug mode and does not contain anything. However, bytes contains the whole byte array received from network.

```
void MainWindow::dataFromServer(QByteArray bytes)
{
//    QByteArray bytes;
    QBuffer    buffer(&bytes);

    QPixmap pixmap;
//    pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(this);

    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    pixmap.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes pixmap into bytes in PNG format

    emit sendPixmapToWidget(pixmap);
}
```

and here I set the pixmap to texture:

```
void GlWidget::pixmapCatchFromForm(QPixmap pixmap)
{
    deleteTexture(texture);

//    image->loadFromData(bytes, "PNG");

    texture = bindTexture(pixmap);

    qDebug() << texture; // returns 1

    updateGL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QPixmap::save(..)` saves the `QPixmap`'s contents to the buffer, surely you want to use `QPixmap::loadFromData(..)` to do the opposite?